# YouTube Live Streaming Overlay

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to implement a YouTube Live Streaming Overlay: the live stream is a sport event and I need to put an overlay with the realtime score of the event.

Here's the questions:

- Is it possibile to add a "native" overlay i.e. mix 2 streams (the video and a fake stream with the score) to produce a single broadcast event?
- Is it possibile to add the overlay client-side with JavaScript? How can I synchronize the livestream (which can be lagged) with the score that is received by JavaScript in realtime?
- Is it possibile to add subtitles in realtime to mimic an overlay with the score?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely overlay the stream, add more metadata etc. But you can not do those with API. You can do the overlay on your own client and stream to YT the final version.

Comment: I ended up mixing 2 signals (streaming and overlay) with a physical video mixer, then sending the built signal to YT

Comment: @Ibrahim do you have any example app where i can see the output? Live stream process is just like Capture video from camera -> show video on mobile screen -> add text over at the bottom of screen just like cricket score / advertisement -> show video with overlay on Youtube. Kindly share your suggestion, if any. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming software often accept a URL that points to an overlay, which is then mixed by that software into the stream before it is sent to YouTube. Such an overlay is normally controlled from a different URL where you manage the scoring of the game. Since the overlay is updated in real-time and mixed before it is sent, there are no timing issues.

There are now several sites providing overlays for different sports. One example is [Uno](https://overlays.uno/home), or if you are curious about the inner workings of such overlays there is an open source project called [scoreboard](https://github.com/Roenbaeck/scoreboard).